# Ubuntu on MSI GP73 Leopard 8RE?

Tags: laptop, compatibility, msi

I'm interested in buying an [MSI GP73 Leopard 8RE Laptop](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GP73-Leopard-8RE.html). What about using Ubuntu on it?

Does it work well?

Can I buy it with Windows 10 and install Ubuntu on first use?

Comment: Related, possibly helpful: [Where can I find a list of computers guaranteed to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/131/301745)

Comment: Related: [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/301745)

Comment: Related: [Is there a easy way to test ubuntu on new notebooks before buying it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/231929/301745)

Comment: I think 8th gen Intel Cores require the new kernel version Ubuntu 18.04 has, but maybe 16.04 has it too by now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! :)

I entered #linuxmint-help IRC channel and with help of orcus and mtn I made my machine really FLYING :) Thanks, guys, one more time. In Mint there is a shortcut to this channel in Welcome Screen.

Now I'm running on Mint 19.1 MATE 64-bit.

The issue was solved by adding nomodeset in grub settings during firts boot (while booting from USB I used Compaltibility Mode). Just hold Shift while it's booting and grub menu appears. With first entry marked press e to edit and add nomodeset parameter to second line from the bottom. You will guess where. There are hints at the bottom of screen how to operate. After installing I didn't have to change anything in grub settings. Just installed nvidia drivers in System Settings; during installation I installed all upgrades and it was good. Exceptions will be described below. In hope for making things even better I also installed newest kernel via Update Manager as guys on IRC channel told me.

The only issue is missing sound and alsamixer did not start. System does not detect soundcard properly so I need to do more research on newest hardware, but for my work sound is the last thing I need to fix.

Edit: Sound on speakers is working now. Next day I discovered that headphones started working (I did nothing in the system). Alsamixer as well, but still silence on speakers. Seems there is a bug. I noticed in alsamixer, that it's muting speakers after connecting headphones and opposite when I unplug. So for test I turned up volume on headphones (unplugged) and speakers started playing. Looks like the program changes only indicators but not real output.

Edit2: I managed to get sound working good enough. Before investigation I thought of 2 things:
1. alsamixer does not store settings
or
2. alsamixer fails to restore settings at boot

After severals tests with saving various states and comparing contents of /var/lib/alsa/asound.state I discovered that it stores the settings correctly but does not restore them at boot. So I added script at start with "alsactl restore" command and it restores volume's levels do default. BTW: when used without sudo it restores to default volumes (initializes soundcard actually) and with sudo - to saved levels.

Problem STILL exists: after unplugging headphones I have to restore settings by manually starting the script.

//End of Edit2

Hibernating and suspending works suspicious. Haven't tested it thoroughly because with that BOOST who would care if the system is suspending or shutting down ;)

I hope someone finds this post useful.

Cheers!

[msi](/questions/tagged/msi) [gp73](/questions/tagged/gp73) [leopard](/questions/tagged/leopard) [8re](/questions/tagged/8re)

Comment: Your information is very useful for me. Thank you. I have a few more questions regarding MSI GP73 Leopard. 1. Is there anything that not works well under Linux? If yes, then what exactly? 2. If you are not making any GPU intensive work (games, etc), how loud in that case are fans? 3. What is your overall impression for MSI GP73 Leopard?

Comment: Hi! I haven't noticed anything bad. Haven't tested HDMI yet. My machine is flying all the time :) The fans are working very nicely and quietly - just normally. My working place is pretty noisy so even if they get louder I can't hear it. At home it's all good. Overall impression? Very very good. LED keyboard is useful sometimes in the dark, but I didn't even check, if there is a software for linux to control the colors. AltGr and Delete - their location differs from my other machines. I just remapped my AltGr with xmodmap and it feels better.

Comment: Thank you. Do you hear laptop fans when you are not playing games and do other things on the laptop?