# Will Ubuntu work on Acer Aspire 5?

Tags: system-installation, acer

I'm considering buying [this laptop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RF2123Z) for my next semester of college. It's an Acer Aspire 5 A515-54-51DJ. I want to erase Windows 10 and install Ubuntu for my OS. I would also consider dual-boot, but would rather not. Before spending $500+, I want to make sure I can install Ubuntu on the hardware. I've searched the web (mainly Acer community and this site), but I can't find an answer.

I would appreciate an answer, links to helpful sites where I might find an answer, or a list of general specifications of what you need to run Ubuntu on a laptop. An answer is best, though.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a easy way to test ubuntu on new notebooks before buying it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231929/is-there-a-easy-way-to-test-ubuntu-on-new-notebooks-before-buying-it) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/)

Comment: The relevant community wiki: [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/37165)

Comment: I was thinking of getting this same model. Were you able to get Ubuntu working on it?

Comment: i guess question should be will WIFI and other important drivers work OOO or needs specific installs ? If specific are they stable ... can have a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ubuntu download page (desktop edition):

> 2 GHz dual-core processor or better
>   4 GB RAM
>   25 GB disk space

Based on this, and the specifications listed at your link, Ubuntu would definitely work effectively on your PC.