# Installing Ubuntu on Asus ROG Strix G513IC-EB73?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, asus, compatibility

I want to buy an Asus ROG Strix G15 G513 on Amazon. One of the reviewers commented:

> The laptop overall for gaming and stuff is great. But I bought it for
> professional use and thought being such a good brand they’ll provide
> linux support which is very essential for me but they didn’t. So if
> you wanna dual boot don’t buy this

Since my idea is to install Ubuntu on my laptop, I wanted to know if indeed this laptop doesn't support Linux based OSs or if there's any way around that.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic. And it is a pure speculation. Asus never provides "linux support" for any products.

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation, I am asking because, since I am not into the subject, I do not understand how come an OS could not be installed on a laptop made of quite standard pieces on the market. Maybe what he meant was "support" in an "User assistance" fashion, and not that the machine does not support linux.

Comment: According to [Linux Hardware](https://linux-hardware.org), this computer [seems to work](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=85cb48e026) with 21.04, although the network controller is not well supported there. It is mentioned that Kernel 5.12 and above supports this, and it does work for [someone](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=06404619aa) with kernel 5.14 and [someone](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=b6ea706618) with kernel 5.12. *However, we cannot guarantee whether it would be compatible with Ubuntu. Buy at your own risk*. Tips: Try Ubuntu 21.10 instead of 21.04 or 20.04.

Comment: *Continued* Ubuntu 21.10 has kernel 5.13, so it might support the network controller (out of the box).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) Also, questions that are "Can I run Ubuntu on my hardware?" will probably be closed per [this Meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17528/1438484). Here, I think it is probably a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/1438484) more generic question.

Comment: @nico_so Who told you that Ubuntu "can't be installed"? Asus doesn't provide support for Linux. I am using a lot of Asus computers with Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a easy way to test ubuntu on new notebooks before buying it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231929/is-there-a-easy-way-to-test-ubuntu-on-new-notebooks-before-buying-it)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party on this one but the answer may be helpful for someone searching with a similar question.

It's very, very simple. When a PC or laptop manufacturer or vendor says they don't support Linux, what they really mean is, "We don't know how to use Linux so don't ask us any questions." In short, they are saying, "DUH! Linux? We only hire Windwoes Drones"

Now, there are two things you can do to circumvent the issue.

First, go to your preferred retail store with a Linux USB flash drive and either insist on testing it or get a commitment from the salesperson that you can return the machine if Linux doesn't work, which is highly unlikely unless you are buying some over-done trash like a Mint Box or other custom designed machine.

Second, the G513 is user-upgradeable so buy a separate NVMe device, remove the one supplied by the manufacturer and replace it with your newly purchased NVMe. Install Linux and pack the original NVMe away. If you ever have to make a warranty claim, simply put the original NVMe back in (it has Windwoes on it), and you're good to go.

As for the G513, and almost all brand name laptops, they run Linux fine.

In summary, "We don't support Linux" is industry code for "Que?"